# Outputting a random forest classification results in Computed value is too large (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

Error: Image.reduceRegions: Computed value is too large. (Error code: 3)
Here is my code. I try to output a random forest classification result in a TIFF file format but it failed.

```
var qualityMask = function(im) {
  return im.updateMask(im.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
      .updateMask(im.select('degrade_flag').eq(0));
};
//输入研究区
var Bound  = ee.FeatureCollection(table);
//可修改年份，从19-22年都可
var dataset1 = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
    .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-09-30')
    .map(qualityMask)
    .select('rh95')
    .median();
var clipped=dataset1.clipToCollection(Bound);
var gediVis = {
  min: 1,
  max: 60,
  palette: 'darkred,red,orange,green,darkgreen',
};
var sample=clipped.toInt();
var vector = sample.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: Bound,
  crs: sample.projection(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13,

});
var vectors=vector.limit(3500);
print(vectors);
//可修改年份，从19-22年都可
var Landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-09-30')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 20)
    .median();
var L8=Landsat8.clipToCollection(Bound);
print(L8);
function NDVI(img) {
 var ndvi =img.normalizedDifference(["B5","B4"]);
 return ndvi;
}
var ndvi = NDVI(L8);
var dataset2 = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')
    .clip(Bound);
var terrain = ee.Algorithms.Terrain(dataset2);
var elevation = terrain.select('elevation');
var slope = terrain.select('slope');
var aspect = terrain.select('aspect');
var L8_B6=L8.select('B6');
var L8_RF=L8_B6
    .addBands(elevation.rename('elevation').toFloat())
    .addBands(ndvi.rename('ndvi').toFloat())
    .addBands(aspect.rename('aspect').toFloat())
    .addBands(slope.rename('slope').toFloat());
var bands=L8_RF.bandNames();
var samples = L8_RF.sampleRegions({
    collection: vectors,
    properties:['label'],
    scale: 30 ,
    tileScale:16
});
var aspenSites = samples.filterMetadata({name:"label", operator:"greater_than", value: 3});
var withRandom = aspenSites.randomColumn('random');
var split = 0.7; 
var trainingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
var testingPartition = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(300)
    .train({
  features: trainingPartition,
  classProperty: 'label',
  inputProperties: bands 
});
var classified = L8_RF.classify(classifier,'predicted');
//修改输出文件、文件夹名称即可
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified,
  region: Bound,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  folder: "th",
  description: "th"
        });
```

Here is the link to my assets:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/dd3875049912f40c92489763899507de